# How to query the list of user who are currently logged in salesforce org using SOQL query so that it can be used in APEX?

Tags: apex, soql, customization

As of now i am using a query to get the list of user who are currently logged in.

Some suolution are there which say that check the field isCurrentlyLoggedIn but no such field exist in salesforce on User Object.

**SELECT Id, CreatedDate, LoginType, LastModifiedDate, NumSecondsValid, SessionType, SessionSecurityLevel, Users.Name,UsersId,UserType FROM AuthSession Where SessionType='UI'**

But I am not sure that this is returning correct list of user or not.

What is the best approach to the solution of this issue?

In the result i wanted the list of user who are currently logged in my org.

Comment: Have you looked at this? 
 https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdm1NUAR/get-a-list-of-all-logged-in-users

Answer (score 0):

You can see currently logged-in users in Setup > Security Controls > Session Management.

For more information: https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=security_user_session_info.htm&siteLang=en_US

You can also use the AuthSession object to use this information in your code: https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm

Query:

```
SELECT Id, CreatedDate, LoginType, LastModifiedDate, NumSecondsValid, SessionType, SessionSecurityLevel, Users.Name, UsersId, UserType, IsCurrent FROM AuthSession WHERE IsCurrent = True AND SessionType='UI'
```

Comment: Thanks.
 Information is good but not able to figure out solution for my query

Comment: @MANANKUMAR I have edited the answer and added the query. Please check and let me know is these work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?,

```
SELECT Id, CreatedDate, LoginType, LastModifiedDate, NumSecondsValid, SessionType, SessionSecurityLevel, Users.Name, UserType, LoginGeo.Country

FROM AuthSession

WHERE Users.Name = 'John Doe' AND isCurrent = true

ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC
```

Based on @TusharJadavs answer